# Why icon link is not displayed? Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I am reading book "ASP .NET MVC 5" and I stuck for a moment... Author uses Bootstrap 3 but next version Bootstrap has a few changes and I can't solve my problem.

Book:

```
<div class="navbar-right visible-xs"> 
<a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Cart", new { returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery })
class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></div>
```

But I used:

```
<div class="navbar-brand d-block d-sm-none">
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Cart", new {returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery})" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</a>
```

In the effect I want see icon link "+". Thats all. But only thing I see it is empty button.

Comment: `visible-xs` is the opposite of `d-sm-none`. The first one will only show up on small devices, the latter one will show up on all but small devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5d3b374b3f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Write the above link in the head section.

Then in the button element writing `<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>` might help you.

Comment: Thx! Pls closed topic.